# Change date and time of a photo in the iOS camera roll?

Tags: ios, photos, photos.app, camera, time

Can I change the date and/or time of photos that are in the iOS camera roll?

I've imported photos, but they now have the wrong date. How can I adjust these photos to appear in the correct temporal order in my camera roll and iOS iCloud Photos library?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can accomplish this by downloading third-party apps from the App Store.

## Pixelgarde

One I've found very popular from my web searches is [Pixelgarde](https://itunes.apple.com/app/pixelgarde/id414677492). This app not only lets you edit the date and time of when your photo was taken, but also change or delete the location where it was taken in, the person who took it, and much more.

---

Again, this is the one I've found most popular in my web searches, but please feel free to pick up the one you most prefer!

Hope this helped you out, let me know !

Answer (score 2):

You can also adjust the date/time if you have access to the Photo app on a Mac computer that automatically syncs to the camera roll on your phone (assuming you are referring to photos on your phone).  Double-click on the photo, then click on the circled "i" next to the heart at the top right corner of the window.  Then, double-click on the date/time section in the window that pops up, and it should let you edit the information there.

Answer (score 2):

iOS 15 in 2021 adds a new **Adjust Date & Time** feature to the iOS Photos app.

1. Scroll up on a photo
2. Press `Adjust` button
3. `Adjust Date & Time` via the calendar, date picker, and time zone selector.

iOS 15 is now capable of adjusting the Date and Time a photo was taken. This was previously only available in the macOS Photos app via `Adjust Date and Time...`.

You can also press and hold the Date on photo, and then press and hold it on another - to Copy and Paste the Date & Time taken. (same works for location)

---

[image: Adjust button]
[image: Adjust Date & Time]

Comment: iOS really gets better with time

Answer (score 0):

**Metadata Pro** is also a good app to change photo date + a lot of other metadata. Works for videos too.

Link:
https://itunes.apple.com/app/metadata-pro/id835505449?mt=8